# jquery $.post MVC controller refresh same view with model return

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, model-view-controller, http-post

i need an help.
i've a mvc view, on tr double click a call a mvc controller and pass th selected tr data

```
    var f = $('#frmUtente');
    var action = f.attr('action');
    var lvm = []
    lvm.push({ name: 'JsonResponse', value: JSON.stringify(data) })
    $.post(action, lvm)
        .done(function (data) {
            $("#divResult").hide();
            showRicerca();
        })
        .fail(function () {
            $('.alert-danger', $('.login-form')).show();
            $('#loader-wrapper').hide();
        });
```

my mvc controller serialize json result and cast into model view, after call the same view vith model

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UtenteEdit(string JsonResponse)
    {
        //recupero credenziali
        UtenteModelView umv = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UtenteModelView>(JsonResponse);
        umv.ModeView = UtenteModelView.MODEVIEW.EDIT;

        return View("~/Views/Home/Create.cshtml", umv);
    }
```

my view is

```
@using ErpLibrary.dao;
@using ErpMvc.Models;

@model ErpMvc.Models.UtenteModelView

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_BasePage.cshtml")

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Utenti";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section css{
    <link href="~/Template/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Template/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/editor/css/editor.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModeView, new { @id = "hMODEVIEW" })
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="portlet box blue" style="border-right: 1px !important;border-bottom: 0px !important;">
                <div class="portlet-title tabbable-line ">
                    <div class="caption caption-md">
                        <i class="icon-globe theme-font hide"></i>
                        <span class="caption-subject" style="font-size: 24px !important;font-weight: 100 !important;">
                            Utenti&nbsp;
                            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw" id="loadUtenti"></i>
                            <a href="#" title="CTRL+F" id="aSearch"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" style="color: black;"></i></a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#tab_1_1" data-toggle="tab">Informazioni</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab_1_3" data-toggle="tab">Password</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab">Avatar</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                    <div class="line-bottom" style="border-top: 1px solid #e7ecf1 !important;margin-top: 60px;"></div>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
                        <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                        <span> Errore: alcuni campi obbligatori non sono stati valorizzati</span>
                    </div>
                    <!--START RICERCA-->
                    <div class="portlet-body form" style="border:solid 1px #e7ecf1;border-top:none;padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;display:none" id="divSearch">
                        <form role="form" action="#" id="frmSearch" name="frmSearch" class="search">
                            <div class="form-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" placeholder="Utente" class="form-control focus" id="pUserid" name="pUserid" /></div></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @{
                                                _Select2View ps2vStato = new _Select2View();
                                                ps2vStato.IdSelect = "pState";
                                                ps2vStato.TypeSelect = TYPE.STATO;
                                                ps2vStato.PlaceHolder = "Stato";
                                            }
                                            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Select2.cshtml", ps2vStato)
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @{
                                                _Select2View ps2vRole = new _Select2View();
                                                ps2vRole.IdSelect = "pRole";
                                                ps2vRole.TypeSelect = TYPE.RUOLO;
                                                ps2vRole.PlaceHolder = "Ruolo";
                                            }
                                            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Select2.cshtml", ps2vRole)
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-actions right ">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn default" id="btnAnnullaSearch">Annulla</button> @*Chiude la form di ricerca*@
                                    <button type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn blue"> Cerca </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!--END RICERCA-->
                    <!--START RESULT-->
                    <div class="portlet-body form" id="divResult" style="border:solid 1px #e7ecf1;border-top:none;padding:15px;display:none">
                        <form role="form" action="#" id="frmResult" name="fmrResult">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <table class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="tableUtenti">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr><td class="dataTables_empty" colspan="5">Nessun risultato</td></tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    @{
                                        _DataTable pw = new _DataTable();
                                        pw.idTable = "tableUtenti";
                                        pw.idSpinner = "loadUtenti";
                                        pw.idLoader = "loader-wrapper";
                                        pw.idSrc = "id";
                                        //add option
                                        pw.options.Add("filter", "false");
                                        pw.options.Add("info", "false");
                                        pw.options.Add("ordering", "false");
                                        pw.options.Add("processing", "true");
                                        pw.options.Add("retrieve", "true");
                                        //add columns DataTables
                                        pw.lsColumn.Add(new Column { Name = "Id", Title = "Identificativo", Orderable = "true", ClassName = "dt-center", Visible = true });
                                        pw.lsColumn.Add(new Column { Name = "Userid", Title = "Utente", Orderable = "true", ClassName = "dt-left", Visible = true });
                                        pw.lsColumn.Add(new Column { Name = "State.text", Title = "Stato", Orderable = "true", ClassName = "dt-left", Visible = true });
                                        pw.lsColumn.Add(new Column { Name = "Role.text", Title = "Ruolo", Orderable = "true", ClassName = "dt-left", Visible = true });
                                        pw.lsColumn.Add(new Column { Name = "TsPwd", Title = "Ts. Psw", Orderable = "true", ClassName = "dt-left", Type = TYPEFIELD.DATETIME, Visible = false });
                                        pw.lsColumn.Add(new Column { Name = "TsState", Title = "Ts. State", Orderable = "true", ClassName = "dt-left", Type = TYPEFIELD.DATETIME, Visible = true });
                                        //add Fields Editor
                                        //CallBack definition
                                        pw.callBackEditForm = "EditUtente";
                                    }
                                    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_DataTable.cshtml", pw)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!--END RESULT-->
                </div>
                <div class="portlet-body form">
                    <form role="form" action="~/Home/UtenteEdit" id="frmUtente" name="frmUtente">
                        <div class="form-body">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <!-- PERSONAL INFO TAB -->
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1_1">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label sr-only">Id</label>
                                                @*<input type="text" placeholder="Identificativo" class="form-control" readonly id="Id"/>*@
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { @placeholder = "Identificativo", @class = "form-control", @id = "Id", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label sr-only">User</label>
                                                @*<input type="text" placeholder="Utente" class="form-control focus" required maxlength="25" id="Userid" name="Userid"/>*@
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Userid, new { @placeholder = "Utente", @class = "form-control focus", @id = "Userid", @name = "Userid", @maxlength = "25", @required = "required" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label sr-only">Stato</label>
                                                @{
                                                    _Select2View s2vStato = new _Select2View();
                                                    s2vStato.IdSelect = "IdState";
                                                    s2vStato.TypeSelect = TYPE.STATO;
                                                    s2vStato.PlaceHolder = "Stato";
                                                    s2vStato.MinimumInputLength = 0;
                                                    if (Model != null) { s2vStato.Selected = Model.IdState.ToString(); }
                                                }
                                                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Select2.cshtml", s2vStato)
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label sr-only">Ruolo</label>
                                                @{
                                                    _Select2View s2vRole = new _Select2View();
                                                    s2vRole.IdSelect = "IdRole";
                                                    s2vRole.TypeSelect = TYPE.RUOLO;
                                                    s2vRole.PlaceHolder = "Ruolo";
                                                    s2vRole.MinimumInputLength = 0;
                                                    if (Model != null) { s2vStato.Selected = Model.IdRole.ToString(); }
                                                }
                                                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Select2.cshtml", s2vRole)
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- END PERSONAL INFO TAB -->
                                <!-- CHANGE AVATAR TAB -->
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1_2">
                                    <p>
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum
                                        eiusmod.
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                                            <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                                                <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"> </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <span class="btn default btn-file">
                                                    <span class="fileinput-new"> Select image </span>
                                                    <span class="fileinput-exists"> Change </span>
                                                    <input type="file" name="...">
                                                </span>
                                                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix margin-top-10">
                                            <span class="label label-danger">NOTE! </span>
                                            <span>Attached image thumbnail is supported in Latest Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari and Internet Explorer 10 only </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="margin-top-10">
                                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn green"> Submit </a>
                                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn default"> Cancel </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- END CHANGE AVATAR TAB -->
                                <!-- CHANGE PASSWORD TAB -->
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1_3">
                                    @{
                                        if (Model == null || Model.ModeView == UtenteModelView.MODEVIEW.NEW)
                                        {
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label sr-only">Current Password</label>
                                                @*<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="Psw" name="Psw" />*@
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Psw, new { @type = "password", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password", @id = "Psw", @name = "Psw" })
                                            </div>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label sr-only">Current Password</label>
                                                @*<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password Corrente" id="Psw" name="Psw"/>*@
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Psw, new { @type = "password", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password Corrente", @id = "Psw", @name = "Psw" })
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label sr-only">New Password</label>
                                                @*<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Nuova Password" id="PswNew" name="PswNew" />*@
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Psw, new { @type = "password", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Nuova Password", @id = "PswNew", @name = "PswNew" })


                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label sr-only">Re-type New Password</label>
                                                @*<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Conferma Password" id="PswNewConfirm" name="PswNewConfirm" />*@
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Psw, new { @type = "password", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Conferma Password", @id = "PswNewConfirm", @name = "PswNewConfirm" })
                                            </div>
                                        }
                                    }
                                    @*<div class="margin-top-10">
                                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn green"> Change Password </a>
                                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn default"> Cancel </a>
                                        </div>*@
                                </div>
                                <!-- END CHANGE PASSWORD TAB -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-actions right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn default" id="btnAnnulla">Annulla</button>
                                <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn blue">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Salva
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my problem is that the view is not refresh vith data model

any idea

thank

Comment: which view (Element)are you expecting to be updated? If you want to update an element with the response coming back, you can do it like `$("#YourElementId").html(data)`

Comment: It looks like the page is reloading after the ajax call.  Are you not seeing the new information after the page reloads?  More specifics on what data you are expecting to refresh would be helpful.